# Collapse Bootstrap 4

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

I recently install a collapse for Bootstrap 4. When I click for show the card, thats fine, works, the problem is with the second click, it doesn't collapse the content. I've posted the code; please let me know if you can identify the problem

```
<div id="accordion">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    Welcome
                </button>
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
                json here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi checked with bootstrap 4. Its working proper.Please find the below link

https://www.codeply.com/p?starter=Bootstrap%204

Paste your code and check its working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Notice on the `<div id="collapseTwo">` the `data-parent` attribute is set to `#accordion`? Be sure to set that attribute to the ID of whatever element contains the accordion, otherwise it will not work.

https://www.codeply.com/p/vmRvzOHcEr